# How to set up SSL certificates for containerized EventHubs message processors?

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, .net-6.0, azure-eventhub

I've been writing an EventHubs message processor that just connects to EventHubs and processes messages on the EventHub. I've been developing in Visual Studio on Windows using .NET 6. Things work as expected on Windows; I can:

1. Connect to EventHubs
2. Receive messages
3. Do the message processing I want

Great. I then wanted to scale my message processor horizontally and decided that I would Dockerize it, and since .NET 6 runs on Linux, I would cross-compile it for Linux and eventually deploy multiple instances of my message processor on Docker Desktop as a next step. I eventually want to stick it on Kubernetes to scale up by an order of magnitude or two.

It was easy to Dockerize my Project in Visual Studio. I simply right-clicked the Project and selected Add -> Docker Support. Visual Studio detected I had Docker Desktop installed and generated all the config files I needed, and added an appropriate build configuration so that I could compile a binary, build a Docker image with it, and automatically deploy it to my local Docker Desktop instance.

.NET 6 also compiled without errors, which was great. However, when my container spins up, I get hit with the following runtime error:

`System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain`

and there is a stack trace (omitted here for brevity) stemming from something in the EventHubs processor library:

`<...many layers...> at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Primitives.EventProcessor-1.RunProcessingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

I am correctly passing my EventHubs connection string to my container, but what I surmise is that my container is missing an SSL certificate or has a misconfigured SSL certificate. I suppose Visual Studio has helpfully silently gone ahead and installed a development certificate when I developed my message processor on Windows so that EventHubs connections "just work" in my development environment, but that SSL certificate is not available to my container, since it isn't part of the build output.

I know I *probably* should be using Azure key vault or whatever secret management service they provide, but how else can I resolve this SSL certificate issue as quickly or painlessly as possible? It would be nice if I can just keep my connection string in my appsettings.json (It's fine. Toy project, only using Azure free credits anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way forward would be to register a handler that participates in certificate validation and can, if desired, override normal handling and force acceptance.   This, of course, comes with the warning that you're bypassing standard security checks and may be putting your network and host in danger.

You don't mention which client you're using, but each takes a set of options in their constructor.  The options for each type have a member named `ConnectionOptions` which returns an [EventHubsConnectionOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubconnectionoptions?view=azure-dotnet) instance that allows you to register a [CertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubconnectionoptions.certificatevalidationcallback?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-eventhubs-eventhubconnectionoptions-certificatevalidationcallback).

The Event Hubs [Influencing SSL certificate validation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample02_EventHubsClients.md#influencing-ssl-certificate-validation) sample demonstrates how to use it.   More information is also available in the .NET documentation for [RemoteCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Thanks for these options. I've managed to get it working by creating a custom RemoteCertificateValidationCallback. I will look into how to set containers up properly with SSL in the future, but I am pleased to see that I can scale my message processor horizontally.